# While file exists in bash

Tags: file, shell, while-loop, exists

Pretty much it checks if the file 'ok.temp' exists. If it doesn't it goes into a loop of sleeping for 2 seconds before checking again. After the file is deemed that it exists it continues on.

Unfortunately I'm getting the errors stated below the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Read the sensor values
if [ ! -f saved.txt ]
then
    touch saved.txt
fi 

#saved values count
sCount=0

#value aggregates
vTTemp=0
vTHumid=0
vTLux=0

#previous aggregates
pTTemp=0
pTHumid=0
pTLux=0

while : 
do
vTemp=0
vHumid=0
vLux=0

if [ $sCount -gt 0 ] 
then
    if [ $(( $sCount % 5 )) -eq 0 ]
    then
        #set previous aggregates as current
        pTTemp=$vTTemp
        pTHumid=$vTHumid
        pTLux=$vTLux

        #reset current aggregates
        vTTemp=0
        vTHumid=0
        vTLux=0
    fi
fi

    while [ ! –f ok.temp ]
    do
        sleep 20
    done

    if [ -f logfile.txt ]
    then
        rResult=`tail -1 logfile.txt`
        rSaved=`tail -1 saved.txt`
        if [ $rResult -eq $rSaved ]
        then
            vTemp=`echo $rResult | cut -d" " -f1`
            vHumid=`echo $rResult | cut -d" " -f2`
            vLux=`echo $rResult | cut -d" " -f3`
            echo $rResult >> saved.txt

            # aggregate results
            vTTemp=`expr $vTTemp + $vTemp`
            vTHumid=`expr $vTHumid + $vHumid`
            vTLux=`expr $vTLux + $vLux`
            echo 'Most recent results recieved from sensor has been saved'
        else
            echo 'Most recent result has already been saved, skipping'
        fi
    fi

    echo '[Previous] Temp:'$pTTemp' Humid:'$pTHumid' Lux:'$pTLux
    echo '[Current] Temp:'$vTTemp' Humid:'$vTHumid' Lux:'$vTLux

    sCount=`expr $sCount + 1`
done
```

And I'm getting these errors:

Line 43 = while [ ! –f ok.temp ]

```
line 43: [: f: unary operator expected
```

Line 52 = if [ $rResult -eq $rSaved ]

```
line 52: [: too many arguments
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Which are lines 43 and 52? (tl;dr)

Comment: Please replace at least the lines that caused the errors. Otherwise, someone who wants to see them has to click the "edited" link. Your problem and the answers below may benefit someone else who comes to this question via search.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a dash in line 43 - It's an [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (copy it and search on that page to see it). Did you copy that code from a blog? They often do such replacements where they shouldn't. The code should read:

```
while [ ! -f ok.temp ]
```

`-eq` is for numbers, not strings - This should do the trick (the quotes are important):

```
if [ "$rResult" = "$rSaved" ]
```

Comment: You have superior vision and as a result win one whole Internet. +1

Comment: Please explain in a little more detail. What should I change?

Comment: @l0b0 No I didn't copy the code from a blog, but I did from a skeleton script example hint from our lecturer off a pdf. I'm amazed you picked up on it actually, you have immaculate eyesight. You sir, are a king amongst men. I thank you!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: LOL! My suspicions have been vindicated: You *do* own the Internet!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because you're using unquoted variables that are empty inside single square brackets. You can fix this by using the preferred double square bracket form or by quoting the variables (doing both isn't necessary).

You have tagged your question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but your shebang says `#!/bin/sh` and the form of your script follows Bourne shell conventions instead of using Bash-specific features. If you'd like, I can comment on how you can take advantage of those Bash features.

Comment: Fixed the string comparison in line 52 by using quotes and == instead of -eq.

Line 43 error continues :(

Comment: @Linky: I can't see any reason that the `while` statement should give you that error. What shell are you using? What's the OS?

Comment: ahhh my apologies. Let's stay with shebang. I'll edit the tag now.

Comment: Using  2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 15:07:30 EDT 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Linky: Which distribution? Debian, CentOS, Ubuntu... Which shell? Dash, Bash symlinked to `sh`...

Comment: I'm unsure. I'm sorry, this is for university and I'm running it via ssh on their linux box.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that some variable is not set or empty in the script. You can set `set -x` to turn on debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables is empty, or contains multiple words. Use quotes:

```
if [ "$rResult" = "$rSaved" ]
```